# Looping over list of list of plots

Tags: r, list

I have four list of plots (each list has 8 plots), where these lists have been compiled as a list.
So, basically; list of 4 lists, where each sub-list has 8 plots.

Now, I need 8 lists as outcome; wherein first element of each of 4 lists generated as a separate list.

Can anyone help over here that how can I use either "lapply" or "for loop" to get required outcome?

I tried following block, but there was no output [ABC -> "NULL"].

```
PlotsA <- list(Plot1.png, Plot2.png,..., Plot8.png)
PlotsB <- list(Plot9.png, Plot10.png,..., Plot16.png) 
PlotsC <- list(Plot17.png, Plot18.png,..., Plot24.png)
PlotsD <- list(Plot25.png, Plot26.png,..., Plot32.png)

All_Plots <- list(PlotsA, PlotsB, PlotsC, PlotsD)
 
ABC <- for (i in seq_along(All_Plots)){
  for (j in length(All_Plots[[i]])){
    x = list(All_Plots[[i]][j])
    x 
  }
}
ABC
```

The outcome I am looking for is...

```
Outcome1
[1]
Plot1.png, Plot9.png, Plot17.png, Plot25.png
Outcome2
[2]
Plot2.png, Plot10.png, Plot18.png, Plot26.png
...
```

and so on.

Further processing include grid of 4 plots (for eg., Plot1.png, Plot9.png, Plot17.png, and Plot25.png). I can do this once I get the aforementioned outcomes.

Comment: It's not clear to me if (e.g.) `Plot1.png` is a PNG file or a recorded plot in R. I think you're hoping to get `Outcome#` plots that are 4-wide combinations of your `Plot#` plots, is that right? If so, look at the `patchwork` package, it might be as easy as `library(patchwork); Outcome1 <- Plot1.png + Plot9.png + Plot17.png + Plot25.png`

Comment: `lapply(1: length(plots), function(i){
  ggsave(plot = plots[[i]], 
         filename = paste(names(plots)[i], ".pdf"), 
         width = 15)
})` try this where plots is the list of plot you have created i have done for pdf replace with .png

Comment: Plot1.png and so on are recorded plots in R generated by looping over 8 excel files.

Comment: @Samarth any dummy data you can provide that would be helpful ..you can `dput(df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`purrr::transpose()` does exactly what you want — takes a list of *n* elements, each with length *m*, and returns a list of *m* elements each with length *n*.

I used strings here as stand-ins for demonstration purposes, but it’ll work just as well with actual plots.

```
library(purrr)

transpose(All_Plots)
```

Result:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "Plot1.png"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "Plot9.png"

[[1]][[3]]
[1] "Plot17.png"

[[1]][[4]]
[1] "Plot25.png"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "Plot2.png"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "Plot10.png"

[[2]][[3]]
[1] "Plot18.png"

[[2]][[4]]
[1] "Plot26.png"


# ... 

[[8]]
[[8]][[1]]
[1] "Plot8.png"

[[8]][[2]]
[1] "Plot16.png"

[[8]][[3]]
[1] "Plot24.png"

[[8]][[4]]
[1] "Plot32.png"
```

*Example data:*

```
PlotsA <- as.list(paste0("Plot", 1:8, ".png"))
PlotsB <- as.list(paste0("Plot", 9:16, ".png"))
PlotsC <- as.list(paste0("Plot", 17:24, ".png")) 
PlotsD <- as.list(paste0("Plot", 25:32, ".png"))

All_Plots <- list(PlotsA, PlotsB, PlotsC, PlotsD)
```

Comment: just curious never used this `purr` function so it will be directly saved into the file?

Comment: okay got it  ' It doesn’t save anything to disk'